# How String object is not receiving data from the editText? - Android

Tags: android, string, android-edittext

I have a problem with this, the editText in the log is sending data but the String is null and the object is null 
this is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_group_chat);

    mSendMessage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtongrupalSend);
    mGetText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textoDeEdicionChat);

    mChat = new GroupalChat();
    mPost = (Post) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("grupal");




    final String lel = mGetText.getText().toString();

    mChat.setMsj(lel);
    mChat.setTiempoMensaje(System.currentTimeMillis());

    mSendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirebaseUtils.getGrupalChatRef(mPost.getId()).push().setValue(mChat).addOnSuccessListener(GroupChatActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                    Log.d("lol", lel);
                    Log.d("jeje", mChat.getMsj());

                }
            });
        }
    });







}
```

the log is not receiving anything
and the string is not receiving anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this `final String lel = mGetText.getText().toString();` inside the click listener and it will work.

```
mSendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String lel = mGetText.getText().toString();
            mChat = new GroupalChat();
            mChat.setMsj(lel);
            mChat.setTiempoMensaje(System.currentTimeMillis());
            Log.d("lol", lel);
            Log.d("jeje", mChat.getMsj());
            FirebaseUtils.getGrupalChatRef(mPost.getId()).push().setValue(mChat).addOnSuccessListener(GroupChatActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Log.d("lol", "Success");    
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Your version doesn't work because `lel` has already been bound to some value before the click listener has even been created.

Comment: Doesnt Works, the mChat.sendMessage(lel); send null

Comment: i tried this but doesnt works, i put this in the onClickLisenter, but the mChat.setMessage(): sends null to a server and send null to a logcat

Comment: Updated code to fix order of initialization for `mChat`. Good to hear it works for you.

Comment: Also, make `mChat` and related variables local to avoid referencing them from elsewhere.